# Ray monitoring fails when binding to empty address

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, ray, rllib

I'm learning to use RLlib. I've been running it in my debugger on an example script, and it works, but for some reason I get an error message about the monitoring service failing. This is the traceback:

```
File "/home/ramrachum/.venvs/ray_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/autoscaler/_private/monitor.py", line 600, in <module>
  monitor = Monitor(
File "/home/ramrachum/.venvs/ray_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/autoscaler/_private/monitor.py", line 205, in __init__
  logger.exception(
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1512, in exception
  self.error(msg, *args, exc_info=exc_info, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 70, in error
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/logging/__init__.py", line 1911, in _LogErrorReplacement
  msg,
File "/home/ramrachum/.venvs/ray_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ray/autoscaler/_private/monitor.py", line 199, in __init__
  prometheus_client.start_http_server(
File "/home/ramrachum/.venvs/ray_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prometheus_client/exposition.py", line 168, in start_wsgi_server
  TmpServer.address_family, addr = _get_best_family(addr, port)
File "/home/ramrachum/.venvs/ray_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/prometheus_client/exposition.py", line 157, in _get_best_family
  infos = socket.getaddrinfo(address, port)
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 955, in getaddrinfo
  for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):

socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

I'm trying to understand why this bug is happening and how I can fix it. The hostname it's trying to use is `''`, which sounds like something that shouldn't work. Working my way up the traceback, I see that in `ray/autoscaler/_private/monitor.py` line 201, there's this logic:

```
addr="127.0.0.1" if head_node_ip == "127.0.0.1" else "",
```

Since in my case, `head_node_ip` is equal to `'192.168.1.116'`, the `else` clause is used and an empty address is passed on `getaddrinfo`.

I'm not sure what the logic of this code is. Can `getaddrinfo` even work with an empty string? How does this service work for people normally? How do I make it not fail?

Comment: Would you try ` pip install 'prometheus_client<0.14'`? Seems to be relevant to this issue: https://github.com/ray-project/ray/pull/23766

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/pull/23766) with `prometheus-client==0.14`.